# why does this keep saying wrong type what can i do to fix it

Tags: java, arrays

it is saying cannot convert double[] to double. what am i doing wrong here? i can to call this method to add to arrays that were asked for earlier in the program. i asked earlier, apparently in the wrong place, and someone said check my methods return type and what i am returning. to me they are the same right? double[] and im returning sum[]

```
    public static double[] add(double[] operand1, double[] operand2){

        double[] sum = new double[operand1.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < operand1.length; ++i) {
            sum[i] = operand1[i] + operand2[i];

            return sum[i];
```

Comment: The error message is very explicit...

Comment: You need to close the curly braces... and return `sum`.

Comment: Regarding the "keep" in your question: Imagine your compiler decides suddenly to become non deterministic and stops saying "wrong type".

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza that wasn't the problem it was just missing a brace which is why it wasn't working. No need to be so mean I just started java class 2 weeks ago. Sorry.

Comment: I don't understand why when I say: "read the error message" means that I'm mean. And even if you just added the end bracket `}` after `sum[i] = operand1...` the error would still be there. If you're taking a class, it would be better asking another student or to the teacher and again, please read the message. That's the first thing you have to do when confronting a message: read it, understand it and analyze around it.

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza Its an online course the teacher doesnt help, and its at your own pace class with 2 other students, so i figured asking a student wouldnt be of much help either, but thanks

Answer (score 4):

The return value of the method is `double[]`, i.e. an array of double. However you are returning a double.

You should probably return `sum` instead of`sum[i]`. And you should return outside the for loop.

```
public static double[] add(double[] operand1, double[] operand2)
{
    double[] sum = new double[operand1.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < operand1.length; ++i) {
        sum[i] = operand1[i] + operand2[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

You should note, however, that you will get an exception if the length of `operand2` array is shorter than the length of `operand1` array. You should decide how to handle that (either require that both input arrays have the same length, or set the output array's length to the minimum of the input arrays lengths).

Comment: It wouldn't compile (for a different reason) if the return wasn't outside of the for loop.

Comment: @Makoto That's true.

Comment: @Eran thank you so much it works great now. Also i do have something earlier in the program that makes sure the arrays are the same amount of numbers thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you return not the whole array, but only one part of it. So `sum` is the type `double[]` (=double *array*) while one value from the array written as `sum[i]` is a `double`. Since your method says it will return a `double[]` you try to return a `double` whitch creates a type mismatch. Since starting a loop and returning the first time it is executed would make no sense, I guess what you tried to do is the following:

```
 public static double[] add(double[] operand1, double[] operand2){

    double[] sum = new double[operand1.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < operand1.length; ++i) {
        sum[i] = operand1[i] + operand2[i];
    } 
    return sum;
}
```

This will return the whole array after the loop is finished filling it.

Comment: yeah, i think you put the same as the guy above you, but that was the issue and im moving right along with my assignment. Thank you